# Fake a flash link with CSS?

Tags: css

We have a .swf file that was created by an external marketing agency some years ago...

300px X 600px ... it has an embedded link to a PDF that they also created..

We want to link to another PDF file that is more marketing friendly...

Is there a way to fake, using CSS, a link to this new PDF?

We have ceased contact with the old marketing agency and never had the original .fla file to edit.

I was thinking I could add a  over the flash file...and somehow create an class for an a href to equal the size of the  and link to this PDF...

Sound feasible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'faking' a link? If you must keep the original `fla` to link to the file, simply rename the old file to something else and save the new file with the old file's name.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the file is encrypted, it's probably much easier if you use an swf decompiler and extract the pdf from there. Try [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) .